# Como usar tag html como <b> em android

Tags: android

tenho um texto e coloquei ele em um dialog , como faço para não ficar aparecendo a tag e sim o efeito dela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(listenerItem.descricao);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.voltar,null);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

em descrição tem uma String com este texto

Comment: Tenta `<strong>`. (estou chutando: eu sou nota 0 em Android =)

Comment: Como você está setando o texto do Dialog? Pode demonstrar o código?

Comment: Fiz a alteração

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935692/how-to-set-part-of-text-to-bold-when-using-alertdialog-setmessage-in-android

Vê se ajuda de algo, acredito que seja o mesmo problema.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395931/how-to-display-the-html-formatted-text-in-the-popup-box-using-alert-dialog-build

Comment: @IlgnerdeOliveira, atualizei minha resposta com seu caso. Verifique se lhe ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você deseja que o conteúdo de um `TextView`, ou qualquer outro componente de texto seja tradado como `HTML`, você deve fazer um parse no conteúdo com [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)) antes de setar o `text`:

**Exemplo:**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Titulo</h2><p><b>Paragrafo com texto em negrito (bold)</b></p>"));
```

**No seu caso:**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        // altere essa linha
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(listenerItem.descricao));
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.voltar,null);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado vou testar

Answer (score 0):

Ao que parece, você não terá apenas um dialog com informações dispostas nesse formato:

**Tópico 1**

Texto do tópico 1

**Tópico 2**

Texto do tópico 2

**Tópico 3**

Texto do tópico 3

Certo? Se este for o caso, acho que seria melhor criar um layout padrão com text_views da seguinte forma:

**text_view_topico_1**

text_view_texto_1

**text_view_topico_2**

text_view_texto_2

**text_view_topico_3**

text_view_texto_3

Pois imagine que você queira trocar a fonte, cor e tipo do tópico. Se você possui 100 arquivos de texto, você teria que editar todas as 100(no mínimo) tags que você escreveu em cada arquivo, mas se você usar text_views bast ir no layout, clicar na text_view, ir em propriedades e alterar a fonte, cor e tipo e automaticamente todos os dialogs irão receber os novos parâmetros de configuração.